# Удаление чисел из списка индекс которых равен самому числу

Tags: функции, list, сравнение, haskell

Начал изучать хаскель. Задача простая, нужно из списка чисел удалить числа, индекс которых равен самому числу.

Не могу понять как правильно сравнить элемент с его индексом. 
Вот код:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  aa <- getLine
  a <- getLine >>= return . words
  let b = ff a ((length a) - 1)
  putStrLn . unwords $ b


f :: [a] -> [a]
f [] = []
f xs = let (h, t) = splitAt 1 xs in h ++ f (drop 1 t)


ff :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
ff [] k = []
ff xs k = if k == -1 then xs else if (toInteger (xs!!k) ) == (toInteger k) then ff (f xs) (k - 1) else ff xs (k - 1)
```

Comment: Изначально пытался сравнивать так: (xs!!k) == k - тоже ошибка

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял как связан ваш код и условие задачи

> Нужно из списка чисел удалить числа, индекс которых равен самому числу.

Один из возможных способов решения

1. Провести zip, чтобы получить список пар - (индекс, значение)
2. Проверить на равенство
3. Использовать map чтобы отбросить индексы

на Haskell

```
let numbers = [0, 1, 7, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 8]

print $ numbers 
print $ map snd $ filter (\ (i, v) -> i /= v) $ zip [0..] numbers
```

вывод

```
[0,1,7,6,4,8,9,7,8]
[7,6,8,9]
```

Другой вариант - использовать `fold`